Solution of the parabolic PDE using Green's function
Green's function for the parabolic PDE is defined as:
$$\Delta G(\vec{x},t,\vec{\xi},\theta)=\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{\xi},t-\theta)$$
Where $G$ satifies the homogeneous initial and boundary conditions. Now if $\theta \in [t_0;t_1] \ \& \ \vec{x}\in V$, then  by solving this integral in two different ways:
$$B(\vec{x},t)=\iiint_V \int_{t_0}^{t_1}[ G(\vec{x},t,\vec{\xi},\theta)(\Delta_{\xi}u(\vec{\xi},\theta)-a\frac{\partial u}{\partial \theta})-u(\Delta_{\xi}G+a\frac{\partial G}{\partial \theta})]d\theta d^3\xi$$
we can obtain solution for $u(\vec{x},t)$. Let's say for Dirichlet condition this solution would look like this:
$$u(\vec{x},t)=\iiint_V \int_{t_0}^{t_1} G(\vec{x},t,\vec{\xi},\theta)d(\vec{\xi},\theta)d\theta d^3\xi \ + \ \iiint_V u_0(\vec{\xi},t_0)G(\vec{x},t,\vec{\xi},t_0) d^3\xi \ - \ \oint_S\int_{t_0}^{t_1}u(\vec{\xi},\theta)\frac{\partial G}{\partial \vec{n}_{\xi}}d\theta dS_{\xi}$$
Now what makes me really confused in this solution is this arbitraty final moment $t_1$. In this analogous solution to the elliptic PDE everything is fine because your boundary is a closed surface and all the interals are well defined. However in this case there is no final time condition and because we have guaranteed uniqueness of the solution we should be able to choose any $t_1$ before which we want the solution and get a the same answer always. It this true? Can you try to explain this intuitively to me?
